# Why doesn't my post-checkout hook fire when creating a new worktree in a bare repository?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I want to run a `post-checkout` script whenever I `git worktree add <branch>` in my bare repository.

So far I've:

- bare cloned the git repo and `cd`'d into it.
- created `hooks/post-checkout` with a simple `echo foo`
- set `chmod +x hooks/post-checkout`
- run `git worktree add master`

However, the `post-checkout` hook isn't run... or at least my `echo` isn't visible.

Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Works for me. Add a shebang if it's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it was `husky` that was changing the git hooks dir in git config. It was enough to simply commit the `post-checkout` hook to the repo under `.husky/`